# How to calculate the residue of the pole of this function?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm learning modular form and run into such function:
$$
j(\tau)=\frac{(2\pi)^{12}+\ldots}{(2\pi)^{12}q+\ldots}=\frac{1}{q}+\ldots
$$

where $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$. (I omitted the details of definition of $j$, I will update if needed.)

Then I was told that $j$ has a simple pole at $\infty$ and the residue of it is 1. I'm confused.

First of all, how to see it is a simple pole? The formula given is in $q$, not in $\tau$, can we just say so from the leading term $\frac{1}{q}$?

Second, I'm not quite understand the residue at $\infty$. Is it just $-Res(j,0)$? Why $j$'s residue at $\infty$ is 1?

Comment: The function $\,j\,$, which seems to be the invariant of an elliptic curve, should be written a little more explicitly in order to try to see what happens at zero to $\,1/q\,$...

Comment: Well, at $\,1/\tau\,$...:)

Comment: @DonAntonio I tried. But if we use $e^z=\sum\frac{z^n}{n!}$ to expand $q$ in term of $\tau$, we get no $1/\tau$ term. Because $1/q$ us just $e^{-2\pi i\tau}$...

Comment: As I fixed above, it must be $\,1/\tau\,$ , so: 

$$j(\tau^{-1})=\frac{(2\pi)^{12}+\ldots}{({2\pi})^{12}e^{2\pi i/\tau}+\ldots}$$

Comment: I still cannot solve it. Now I think I need to calculate the residue of $\tau^{-2}j(\tau^{-1})$ at $0$. It is $\tau^{-2}(e^{-2\pi i/\tau}+\cdots)$. After expanding $e$, there is still no $\tau^{-1}$ term, right?

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is holomorphic for $|z|>r$, then
$$\mathrm{Res}(f, z=\infty)=\mathrm{Res}(w^{-2}f(w^{-1}), w=0)$$

Moreover, usually $\tau$ is considered to be in the upper half plane or in some fancier (and smaller) domain; therefore, I think that the residue is considered at $q=\infty$.

Anyway, if $f(q)=\frac{1}{q}+g(q)$ with $g$ holomorphic,
$$\frac{1}{p^2}f(1/p)=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p^2}h(1/p)$$
so the residue of the latter at $p=0$ is $1$.
You can also say that the residue at $\infty$ is minus the residue at $0$, but only if you know that the function is holomorphic elsewhere.

Comment: But $j$ is a function of $\tau$, $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$  is just a change of variable. Can we just calculate the residue using the expansion with respect to $q$ rather than $\tau$?

Comment: is your expression for $j$ defined for all $\tau\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: No, for $\tau$ in the upper half plane.

Comment: So it is meaningless to ask for the residue at $\tau=\infty$. You need to have the function defined in a *neighborhood* of $\infty$, i.e. for $|\tau|>R$. Therefore, you go to the universal covering through the exponential map and compute the residue with respect to the new coordinate $q$.

Comment: Your word sounds right. So what if we regard $j$ as being defined on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: How? I mean, what formula would you like to use? Anyway, there is no point in it. The function $j(\tau)$ has NO residue at infinity, because you cannot expand it in a Laurent series around $\infty$. On the other hand, the function $j(q)$ IS defined on the whole plane, so you can consider its residue at $q=\infty$, which is not the same as $\tau=\infty$. Take for example $\tau_k=1+ki$ (which obviously goes to $\infty$ with $k$), then the corresponding $q_k$ don't go to $\infty$, but are all on the circle $|q|=e$...

Comment: Yes. The book says exactly the same and it defines $j(\tau)$ be holomorphic at $\infty$ by $j(q)$ be holomorphic at 0, because when Im$(\tau)\rightarrow \infty$, $q\rightarrow 0$. Oh I suddenly realize that the book maybe saying that with respect to $q$, $j(q)$ has residue 1 at $\infty$...

Comment: When $\mathrm{Im}\tau\to\infty$, $q$ doesn't have a defined limit: if you only know that $y\to\infty$ and you don't know anything about $x$, $\exp(x+iy)=e^x(\cos y + i\sin y)$ doesn't have a limit. $j(\tau)$ isn't holomorphic at $\infty$, $j(q)$ is neither, but it is meromorphic there and has a simple pole. And yes, the only residue which is meaningful to calculate is $\mathrm{Res}(j(q), q=\infty)$.

Comment: OK, I got it, thanks!